# ffmpeg not opening in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg

I downloaded ffmpeg from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

```
ffmpeg-release-full.7z
```

I have extracted it in C: drive. I can see ffmpeg in bin folder of extracted zip.

When I try to run it using command prompt in Windows 10,

[image]

it says:

[image]

This app can't run on your PC

I also tried setting compatibility mode to Windows 7 for this program through properties, but still same problem.

Output of SET PROC command:
[image]

Comment: You need a tool to extract the `7z` archive. Maybe you like this one: https://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract .7z files?](https://superuser.com/questions/254086/how-do-i-extract-7z-files)

Comment: Can you show the output of `set proc` in Command Prompt?

Comment: This looks to be a permission issue, based on the first image, not related to build compatibility.

Comment: @Gyan - I am running the command prompt under administrative rights.